# Simple HC-05 Bluetooth Communication with Android App

Tags: java, android, class

Im trying to build up an app for a simple HC-05 bluetooth comm. All i need my activity to do is to find the HC05 module, connect to it, send an int+char and then stay put for a while until the process on the HC05 module ends. When this happens, the app will listen for a end string and show on screen the process is done.  I need the comm to be both ways. I dont know where to start, im pretty new at this. Ive seen plenty of methods using getPairedDevices() but i want this to be short and simple like a point on point connection using a wire. Also those methods are like no discovery and listing at all. For those to work i would have to first pair the phone to the HC05. Its no scalable.

I would really appreciate some advice please.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thing is i dont have "a code" but samples i ve been looking at but nothing to certain. I dont really know how to do it. I need a java bluetooth tutorial for bi lateral comm